# Group by count over a collection of nested json array documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data in mongo collection in the following format:

```
{
  "response":[
      {
          "_responsedata":{
              "Error":{
                  "message":"BMERROR001 - Something went wrong. Please check the error logs",
                  "statusCode":"400",
                  "reasonCode":"BMERROR001"
              }
          },
          "_responsemeta":{
              "status":"400"
          }
      },
      {
          "_responsedata":{
              "Error":{
                  "message":"BMERROR001 - Something went wrong. Please check the error logs",
                  "statusCode":"400",
                  "reasonCode":"BMERROR001"
              }
          },
          "_responsemeta":{
              "status":"400"
          }
      },
      {
          "_responsedata":{
              "Error":{
                  "message":"BMERROR002 - Something went wrong. Please check the error logs",
                  "statusCode":"400",
                  "reasonCode":"BMERROR002"
              }
          },
          "_responsemeta":{
              "status":"400"
          }
      },
      {
          "_responsedata":{
              "name":"name1",
              "col1":"value1"
          },
          "_responsemeta":{
              "status":"204"
          }
      },
      {
          "_responsedata":{
              "name":"name2",
              "col1:":"value2"
          },
          "_responsemeta":{
              "status":"201"
          }
      },
      {
          "_responsedata":{
              "Error":{
                  "message":"BMERROR003 - Something went wrong. Please check the error logs",
                  "statusCode":"400",
                  "reasonCode":"BMERROR003"
              }
          },
          "_responsemeta":{
              "status":"400"
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

This ihe format of one documents and I have many documents in the same format. Now for making this documents in a format, which can be visualized using D3, I need to group them based on the `reasonCode` field. So I need something like this as a result :

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code":"BMERROR001",
            "count":2
        },
        {
            "code":"BMERROR002"
            "count":"1"
        },
         {
            "code":"BMERROR003"
            "count":"1"
        }
     ]
}
```

I tried with the following aggregation, but it is giving the reason as an array and the count.

```
[{$group: {
  _id:{
    "reason":"$response._responsedata.Error.reasonCode"
  },
  count:{$sum:1}
}}]
```

How can I take the count grouped by the `reasonCode` properly ?

Comment: Use `$unwind` before `$group`. `{ $unwind: '$response' }` as it is an array.

Comment: Perfect. Working fine. If you can add this as an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `$unwind` the `response` array first then you can apply `$group` on nested `reasonCode`.

```
[
  { $unwind: "$response" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        reason: "$response._responsedata.Error.reasonCode"
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: There is a small problem. It is showing the success records also with reason as null.

Answer (score 0):

For those having a **deep-nested** arrays, you can do it like so:

```js
{
  "pets": [
    "dogs": [
      "name": "douge",
      "quantity": 5
    ]
  ]
}
```

query

```js
[
  { $unwind: "$pets" },
  {
    $unwind: {
     path: "$pets.dogs",
     preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
     _id: null,
     sum: { $sum: "$pets.dogs.quantity" }
    }
  }
]
```